# The last finite difference of $P$ considering in a general form

Tags: finite-differences

> **Problem:** Consider a polynomial (monic) $P$ and finite differences as $Q(x):= P\left(x+\tfrac{1}{2n}\right)-P(x)$ and so on, for any real $a$. Show that the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \dbinom{n}{k} P\left(x+\frac{1}{2n} \cdot k\right)=\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^d d!$$
> where $d=\text{deg} P$

We know that the resulting $d^{\text{th}}$ difference is $\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^d d!$ but how to prove that the above expression is the same?

Thank you!

EDIT: Here is the relevant [link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c487h2378332p19479392) to avoid any confusion of some sort.

Comment: We know that is true, but how to show the same differently?

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that.